# Spring Boot Quartz - Show SQL statements

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I'm using Quartz together with Spring Boot and postgres database as a persistence storage for quartz stuff. I would like to see sql logs in a console which quartz is executing under the hood. I tried many configuration properties to enable it, but none of them worked. Can someone tell me how to enable it? I used following props so far:

```yaml
spring:
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: NEVER
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          jobStore:
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: true

logging:
  level:
    org:
      quartz: DEBUG
      hibernate:
        SQL: DEBUG
      postgres: DEBUG
      springframework:
        jdbc:
          core:
            JdbcTemplate: DEBUG
            StatementCreatorUtils: TRACE
```